# Android : Detect history.back() in WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webkit, webview

A button in my `WebView` is used to go back using the `history.back()` JavaScript call. I do not understand much of JavaScript, but after a bit of searching I found that we can use the `addJavascriptInterface()` method of a `WebView`.

Now, I intend to finish my Activity when the button is clicked. I landed up having something of this sort:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
private static final String sTag = "MyActivity";

private WebView mWebContent;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.browser_page);


    mWebContent = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webContent);

    mWebContent.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebContent.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    mWebContent.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebContent.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "history"); //history.back();

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {
        mWebContent.loadUrl(extras.getString("URL"));
    }
}

    public class JavaScriptInterface {
        JavaScriptInterface() {
        }

    public void back() {
        Log.v(sTag, "back pressed");
        MyActivity.this.finish();
    }
}
}
```

But unfortunately when the button is pressed the Activity doesn't finish, neither do I get anything in the Log.

Here is the html for the button :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">
   <img src="images/btn-go-back.png" onClick="history.back();" border="0" />
</a>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

---

**Edit :** Just wanted to clear the fact that changing the html is not an option for me. I have no power over the the html code :). I have to handle it in the application.

---

**Edit:** Tried changing `history.back()` to `window.history.back()` (locally), still no change.

---

**Edit :** I was experimenting by locally loading html conent and found out that if I change `history.back()` to say something like `android_app.back()` and register my `JavaScriptInterface` by the name`android_app` it works fine. Why is that? Does that mean that we can't use `history` to register an interface? Does the developer docs mention this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching and asking I have finally arrived at the conclusion that you **cannot** add a java script interface, using `addJavascriptInterface (Object obj, String interfaceName)`, with the interface name as `history` (or perhaps any javascript keyword).

Maybe this is written somewhere in the developer docs or manual, but I couldn't find it though.

Answer (score 3):

Read the **Navigating web page history** section of this article.
It tells completely about the android webviews.It tells about how to make webviews handle history.

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Sreeram. But you see I have gone through the sites and have implemented exactly as written there. And Still my Activity wouldn't finish. Could you please go through my code, and see if there is something I'm missing?

Comment: Hi Aki,Just tell me if you want to handle the page navigation in a webview or you want to do something from android side?

Comment: @Aki I have read your edited message.Strange that you mentioned when you changed your javascriptinterface name from history to android_app.I have gone through the developer docs.there is nothing on this.

Answer (score 1):

Try
`<a href="#" onclick="window.history.back()"><img src="bla" /></a>`

edit: just read you can't change the HTML code .. Don't see a solution then ..

Comment: I cannot change the html code, I'll have to do something from the application

Comment: Just a very small comment, the API doc says: Do not use addJavascriptInterface() unless all of the HTML in this WebView was written by you: [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29). I understand that might not be an option ...

Comment: Well it says that its dangerous as it can be used by someone to run malicious code in my app, but in my case that someone is a trusted guy, so it really doesn't matter. By the way, I tried changing it to `window.history.back()` (experimenting locally), and it still doesn't work.

Comment: On the `a href` or on the `img`?

Comment: changed the `href` to `#` and the `img` `onClick` to `window.history.back()`

Comment: So you didn't put `onclick` in `href` as I suggested initially? I have very similar code in a working application, so I think it's worth trying.

Comment: @Aki let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2881/discussion-between-bart-blommaerts-and-aki)